# Splash screen: using handler

Tags: android, handler, splash-screen

Am I doing it right?
I have a Splash screen (just an image), and `onCreate()` I start the main activity after running a heavy function:

```
SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT=2500;
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
public void run() {
     LONG_OPERATING_FUNCTION(); 

     Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); 
     Splash.this.startActivity(mainIntent); 
     Splash.this.finish();
} 
}, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT);
```

I think I have a memory leak, and I'm trying to find it.
I don't think the Splash really is finishing.

Comment: Whats the reason that you think you have a memory leak?

Comment: You said you put this code inside onCreat(). Do you mean your Splash is an Activity itself? Also, what is the Splash in your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`LONG_OPERATING_FUNCTION()` should not be done on the main application thread, as you have it here.

Ideally, you do not use a splash screen, but rather only enable selected features of `MainActivity` while do your `LONG_OPERATING_FUNCTION()` in an `AsyncTask` or something.

If somebody is pointing a gun at your head and forcing you to implement a splash screen lest it be your brains that get, er, splashed, I would do this:

- Eliminate your `Handler` and `postDelayed()` call
- Replace that with an `AsyncTask`
- In `doInBackground()` of `AsyncTask`, do your `LONG_OPERATING_FUNCTION()`
- If, when `LONG_OPERATING_FUNCTION()` is done, `SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT` [sic] time has not elapsed, use `SystemClock.sleep()` to sleep for the remaining time (or not)
- In `onPostExecute()`, start `MainActivity` and call `finish()`

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        openingSound = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.applause);
        openingSound.start();
        setContentView(R.layout.firstanimal);
        Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    Intent openingSplash = new Intent("com.softech.LearnAnimal1.STARTINGPOINT");
                    startActivity(openingSplash);
                }
            }
        };

        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        openingSound.release();
        finish();

    }
```

**This is a complete java code in this u'll have openingSound with 5 seconds break and then u it'll move on your menu or second activity but remeber one thing u also have to put activity with intent filters in your manifest :) 
Enjoy :)**

Answer (score 2):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

通过使用getApplicationContext()的context就不会内存溢出;

public class RunnableActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println("RunnableActivity onCreate");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 3000);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    System.out.println("RunnableActivity onResume");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    System.out.println("RunnableActivity onPause");
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    System.out.println("RunnableActivity onDestroy");
}

private Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    private WeakReference<Activity> weak = new WeakReference<Activity>(RunnableActivity.this);

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Activity a = weak.get();
        if (a != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(a.getApplicationContext(), AActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            a.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
            a.finish();
        }
    }
};}
```

Comment: Use English language